# How to run just one Function inside UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Does anybody know how to solve this code. I have a carousel, and there is **previous** and **next** icon. When clicked, I have to run a specific function inside useEffect().

I want to run the plusSlides() function, which simply calculates the new main carousel picture.

The code is:

```
function Carousel({ children }) {

  useEffect(() => {

    var slideIndex = 1;

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }


  });

  return (
    <CarouselStyled visible={visible}>

      <div className="slideshow-container">
        <div className="container">
          <Link href={`/${router.locale == "bs" ? "" : "en"}`}>
            <a className="mylogo">
              <img src="/logo.svg" alt="Doxat" />
            </a>
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className="mySlides fade">
          <img src="/images/doxat-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div className="mySlides fade">
          <img src="/images/doxat-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div className="mySlides fade">
          <img src="/images/doxat-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <a className="prev" onClick={() => plusSlides(-1)}>
            /* When clicked here, the plusSlides function has to be run*/
          <MdChevronLeft />
        </a>
        <a className="next">
          <MdChevronRight />
        </a>
      </div>
    </CarouselStyled>
  );
}
```

Comment: You mean `useEffect` is called twice instead of one?

Comment: Just extract those functions outside `useEffect`, then call `this.plusSlides` from within (you'll have to use a function). Also you are missing the dependent, which is passed in as a second param of useEffect, the function is only called once the dependent us updated.

Comment: `useEffect` is to execute some piece of code on rerenders. You should not use it to define reusable functions, they should be defined at your component Body

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")` is really not the react way of doing this... use expressions in JSX to hide and show instead...

Answer (score 0):

your function need definition on useEffect() outside,then because you use function component,just call plusSlides can work

```
function Carousel({ children }) {

   const plusSlides = ()=>{
      // do somthing
   }

   useEffect(()=>{

   },[])

   return(
      <div>
          <a className="prev" onClick={() => plusSlides(-1)}></a>
      </div>
   )
}
```